# File Recovery software for ubuntu 13.10 32-bit

Tags: data-recovery

```
  Just a mont ago I copied pdf files from windows mount 'C:\' to linux OS home folder.
```

But since I was new to Ubuntu.while resolving oerheating problem through installing drivers My Ubuntu turned blank screen. So now I have Installed Ubuntu 13.10-32-bit again with bumblebee project.I have solved over heating problem .But my pdf files are lost.
I want good file recovery software for ubuntu which can scan windows mount sda3 and recover those file(2.3GB).

On linux partition 'C:\' drive Is shown with name '2EE8844CE88413ED' .

Answer (score 0):

Check this link i think it can help you , i tried this program .

[Recovery tool](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

Or you can use Hirens boot cd it contain a lot of such tools .